# Is there a way to jump to the line containing an error in an iPython/Jupyter notebook?

Tags: debugging, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When there is an error in a notebook, it simply spits out the error message below the code and one has to manually scan the output for the line in which the error occurred. I've been wondering whether there is maybe an extension or trick to automatically jump to the line containing the error. I have searched the web, but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the pdb magic built in: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html